# Jquery UI - resizable with grid and table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have:

```
<table id="table" border="1">
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div class="test">test</div></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><div class="test">222</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

and:

```
$( ".test" ).resizable({
    grid: [50, 50],
    containment: '#table'
});
```

in my example not working option containment. Why? I want use grid with table and i would like use also containment. Now i can resize .test to outside #table. This is bug? I would like resize max to last TD in my table#table.

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/27KBk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than making each individual cell within the table have the `position` property set to `relative`, you should change your CSS so that it's just the table itself that has that property:

```
table {
    position: relative;
}

table td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/27KBk/1/